# boost::exception vs. std::nested_exception

Tags: c++11, boost, exception

Both boost::exception and std::nested_exception solve the problem of aggregating context, but in different ways. boost::exception allows for adding data with the stream operator. std::nested_exceptions allow for adding a nested exception to the original one with throw_with_nested().

I am now wondering about pros and cons of each. I generally like to stick to the standard stuff as much as possible, but is there a compelling reason for picking boost::exception over nested exceptions?

Comment: Ha. If I could be so audacious, do you have a good example of using `std::nested_exception` that demonstrates that it's useful (especially the part where it might integrate tightly with the standard library?). I've been trying to find out before, but didn't get it.

Comment: I am not sure about "good" and "useful" but here is one example: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/nested_exception#Example

Answer (score 0):

well, you already answered it in the question - "boost::exception allows for adding data with the stream operator", that is almost arbitrary data to use however required, including predefined errinfo_nested_exception. std::nested_exceptions is rather limiting in comparison